# How to deploy an asp.net project project1, with its referred project project2 in same hosting server in httpdoc folder?

Tags: asp.net, iis, deployment, web-hosting

I created an asp.net project project1 in visual studio .NET c#, this project project1 refers to another project project2, my main problem is that in the deployment server there is HTTPDOC folder that can contain only one project and its default.aspx file.

How can I deploy another project project2 in the same (HTTPDOC) folder with all references?

Answer (score 0):

Those other referenced projects for the most part can't really be a web site project. So, for external library code, other class projects etc., then sure, referencing or including that project works fine.

But, for another web site projects? Then which web config will and can be used to define the sites properties? In other words, is that included project to by some act of magic become another WHOLE DIFFERENT web site?

In MOST cases using Plesk or other IIS server web hosting, there is the ability to define/set/change that a sub folder of a given site is to be considered ANOTHER web site - only that it exists inside of Plesk the current project.

Thus, in IIS, you can right click on that sub folder, and use the option "Add Application". This "now" tells IIS to consider that sub folder its OWN web site.

This option:

[image]

However, it makes VERY little sense to include multiple web projects inside of one existing web project.

If you want to publish the 2nd web site to the "existing" site, then fine, as noted from IIS you have to THEN set/tell/inform IIS that this sub folder is in fact to be considered another separate site - the above dialog is how you do this.

Now, above applies to IIS and webforms projects. However, really, at the end of the day, the idea of including other projects into the existing project is a fine idea, but attempting to include multiple web site projects into one project does not make a whole lot of sense. I would as a result thus publish each web site separate using the publishing wizard. And if such a publish is going to reside into an existing web site, then from IIS you need to set/tell/inform IIS that folder is to be considered a whole new web site.